# What is the Command Line Syntax to create a Windows Local User and Add that User to a Local Group?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, command-line-interface

What is the command line syntax to create a windows local user and add that user to a local group?

Can I do it with something short and simple with net commands?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
net user username password /add

net localgroup groupname username /add
```

Comment: net group says "This command can be used only on a Windows Domain Controller"

Comment: @Kyle: Sorry, typo. See edit.

Comment: Ah, came back to fix, you fixed it for me :-)

Comment: Well played, sir.  Beat me to it...  +1 to you

Comment: Add a `/Y` to answer `yes` to some prompts, e.g. complaints about the given password being too long for Win2k boxes