# Fully fleshing out a local user account added via command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, user-accounts

I am working at a customer site commissioning a bunch of Windows 7 systems that were just delivered.  The systems were imaged with a basic setup that included all of the main software needed for the customer *except* for a local (non admin) account that is required for this application.

I know that I can run the [`net user`](https://serverfault.com/questions/185159/what-is-the-command-line-syntax-to-create-a-windows-local-user-and-add-that-user) command to programmatically add the desired local account.  However this command does not fully set up the local account.  You still need to log into it (and see the *your desktop is being prepared* message) before the complete windows configuration has been performed for that account.  But I don't want to do that - I just want to run my powershell script and say "Done!"

So after running `net user` is there anyway via command line or powershell action to trigger the process that  fully fleshes out the account?

**Edit**

My end goal is to have access to the Startup folder for the account I am creating so that I can copy in some shortcuts.  And to do all of this via a powershell script with ***NO*** user interaction.

**Edit 2**

And while I need the solution to work under powershell 2, I am also interested in seeing any solution that works under any later powershell version

Comment: The title of your question says one thing, but then the text says "I already know how to do that thing that I asked in my title but what I _really_ want to do is ..." It sounds like what you're asking for is a way to programmatically simulate an interactive logon. And I don't think there is one. It might not be possible to do what you're asking to do. But - simply running a program with runas.exe specifying the other user's account, while not an interactive logon, is capable of creating a profile. Not sure if it's enough but it's worth a try.

Comment: @RyanRies Point taken about the title.  I'll edit it ASAP.  And I hadn't thought of runas .. I will give that a try.

Comment: @RyanRies `Runas` fails for me.  It seems it requires a password for the account and the account I am trying create doesn't have one.  `1327: Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed, logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.`

Comment: Maybe you could give the user a password with `net user username  newpassword`

Comment: @RyanRies Unfortunately the whole point of this additional account is that it doesn't have a password.

Comment: OK, well in order to allow your user to perform a network logon with a blank password, you need to disable the setting `"Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only"` However, there's no way to do that programmatically AFAIK. You have to do it through the Local Computer Policy mmc snapin. But I did confirm with my test user that using runas with a blank password did create a profile for the user.

Comment: @RyanRies This is for a local account

Comment: I know. I tested it using a local account. I also forgot to mention `net user test /passwordreq:no`

Comment: You can always set a password for the user then run `psexec.exe` with the new password and then remove the password again using `net user`. A profile folder for the user is created under `C:\users` but the registry hive files are not there

Comment: @RyanRies I still get the `'preparing you desktop` message and not all of the account is created. Of course right now I am testing on Home Premium rather than Professional (long story) and don't have the mmc.  I supposedly edited a registry key that does the same thing, but I still have to hit <enter> to submit a blank password when executing `run as`

Comment: Is your goal to just access the Startup folder to copy some shortcuts into it like stated in your __Edit__?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Wondows 7 Professional.

First to say, you will see the *Your Desktop is beeing prepared* message on first logon.

BUT: your goal, adding shortcuts to Startup, is achivable and working.

1. create a file with following content and save it to desired destination as *.reg file:

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Lsa]
   "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa]
   "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
   "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
   ```

This enables interactive logon for accounts with blank passwords ([referrence1](https://superuser.com/a/470539/614417)) ([referrence2](https://superuser.com/a/342686/614417))

1. start an elevated cmd prompt
2. import the regkey

   ```
   regedit.exe /s "C:\tmp\reg.reg"
   ```
3. Create your user account

   ```
   net user /ADD <username>
   ```
4. run `runas` as your created user. I started ping and redirected its output to NUL to wait for the profile to be generated.

   ```
   echo | runas /env /profile /user:<username> "cmd /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 >NUL"
   ```
5. Make Startup directory for your user

   ```
   mkdir "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
   ```
6. Create a shortcut in Startup folder, e.g. via powershell script ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9701907))

Done. As I mentioned, when first logging in you'll see *Your Desktop is beeing prepared* but the the startup is working correctly.

Comment: Your Step 4 does not seem to work from within a powershell script as written.  It is possible CMD `echo` behaves differently to powershell `echo`